# where can i find the file for the colored "mentions"

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, css, localisation, messages

When registering for example you get a green "message" on your screen to let you know you registered, and other messages. errors in red

What file is that in, i'd like to translate but can not find the file..., also i'd like to change colors, is that in a css file?

Answer (score 0):

The word you're looking for is "flash" or notification messages. In Magento and in other MVC frameworks, they are usually set into the session in the controller. For example, `Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController`, sets various flashes to the session according to the flow of the process.

To actually retrieve and display these messages, you do `$this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml()`, which will return all messages stored in the session. `getMessageBlock()` is available to any block class, as it is a method of `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`.

The styling can be changed with CSS. The class name is `messages`.

Answer (score 0):

So it is a bit general but Magento will pass these messages through a translation function, this may not be the case for all 3rd part modules though. This means to translate the text you simply need the text your want to translate, the text your want to translate it to and the language your are working in.

A general translation file can easily be created on a theme level. What you will need to do is create your file in the following page.

```
app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/locale/en_US/translate.csv
```

This would be a translation file for American English, but you can replace en_US with whatever you need.

What you then need in your csv file is two string. Base text and translated text.

```
"This is the normal text","This is the translated text"
```

As for styling this can be done via css the different options are as follows.

```
.error-msg
.success-msg
.notice-msg
.warning-msg
```